# How to self check data in oracle and insert data

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi Everyone here is my following situation

Query1:

```
select part_no, contract, vendor_no
from PURCHASE_PART_SUPPLIER_TAB
 where part_no in (select distinct(part_no)
                   from IC_PARTS_FILE_TAB
                  ) and
       contract = '42';
```

Output1:

[image]

Contract(Site) table

Query2 :

select contract as site from site_tab;

Output2:

[image]

1. By using the first query I get 20 results with partno,site,vendor no.
2. In the 2nd query I am having site table where I have around 50 site.
3. As mentioned in the first query 042 is my master data which has different vendors for different parts.
4. I want to take vendor and part_no from the query 1 and check whether the part and vendor is available for the each site in query 2. If it's available I don't need to do any action but if it's not available I have to insert part_no and vendor for the site which is not available in purchase_part_supplier_tab

Comment: Please edit the question and provide sample data and desired results.  What you are really trying to do is unclear.

Comment: For example (following up on Gordon's comment): what is a "site"? There is no mention of "site" in your query or in the output. What is a "remaining" site? Read your question but pretend, if you can, that you DON'T know what the problem is about. Do YOU understand the question? If you don't, how can we?

Comment: Hi Gordon Linoff & mathguy can you help me out whether i have to compulsory go to pl/sql coding

Answer (score 1):

This is my interpretation of your requirement

- for every combination of VENDOR and PART defined by CONTRACT=42 ...
- create a new record for each CONTRACT in SITE_TAB ...
- where there is no existing record for the combination of VENDOR, PART and CONTRACT.

Try:

```
INSERT INTO PURCHASE_PART_SUPPLIER_TAB
(vendor_no, part_no, contract)
SELECT vendor_no, part_no, st.contract 
FROM 
  PURCHASE_PART_SUPPLIER_TAB ppst
    CROSS JOIN
  SITE_TAB st
WHERE ppst.contract = '42'
  AND part_no IN (SELECT part_no FROM IC_PARTS_FILE_TAB) 
  AND st.contract<>ppst.contract -- don't bother joining to master
  AND NOT EXISTS
    ( SELECT *
      FROM PURCHASE_PART_SUPPLIER_TAB
      WHERE vendor_no = ppst.vendor_no
        AND part_no = ppst.part_no
        AND contract = st.contract
    )
```

Comment: Your solution is tidier than mine was, so I've deleted my post. I added my interpreting though, because I'm not sure the OP's requirement is clear. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @APC your edit has improved the answer as the what to me most time was determining the requirement. Once expressed in this way, the SQL is just the fallout.